# How to Morphia ignore extra field/element?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

i'm newbie and when i using morphia java mongodb I have a problem.
I have "news" database in mongodb with the collection is "article"
an example article:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("54b77156d52fbb115abbc7ed"),
   "title": "test title",
   "thumbnail": "http://test.com/images/2015/01/15/kt169333-1.jpg",
   "imgsLoc": "/home/test/public/images/2015/01/15/kt169333-1.jpg",
   "sapo": "SampleSapo",
   "author": null,
   "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
   "source": "http://example.com/news/test/1",
 ... [it has more about 30 fields after this line ...]
}
```

My job only need get content and save textLength field of the new article.
out put like that:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("54b77156d52fbb115abbc7ed"),
   "title": "test title",
   "thumbnail": "http://test.com/images/2015/01/15/kt169333-1.jpg",
   "imgsLoc": "/home/test/public/images/2015/01/15/kt169333-1.jpg",
   "sapo": "SampleSapo",
   "author": null,
   "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
"textLength": NumberLong(441) <= new field
   "source": "http://example.com/news/test/1",
 ... [it has more about 30 fields after this line ...]
}
```

When i using morphia
because i only need get `content` to caculate `textlength` so i don't care other field.
but when i use morphia. other field is lost, only content and textLength field was save in database;
My article class to map is:

```
public class Article {
@Id
protected ObjectId id;
protected String content;
protected long textLength;

// Getset method
```

}

Why other field is lost?

what is the fastest way to update collection without lost data?
How to ignore extra fields when map this Article class to mongodb?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you don't show it in your code, I assume you're using a save on the document. Thus you replace it with the attributes you have, hence the "missing" fields.

If you don't want to map the whole document, you need to update the fields explicitly instead of simply calling save. See the [Morphia documentation on updates](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Updating).

Comment: yes. i don't want to map the whole document, i try to use update query but i have same result all other fields is lost. only `id` `content` `textLength` -  which properties i declare in Article class is kept- other is lost. This is code update <blink>
Query<Article> query = ds.createQuery(Article.class).field("id").equal(article.getId());
UpdateOperations<Article> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(Article.class).set("textlength", article.getContent.length());
ds.update(query, ops);
</blink>

Comment: Strange. But why are you using Morphia anyway, if you only want to set a single field? The Java driver would be the better solution IMHO

Comment: What does the write concern of the Java driver (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.java) have to do with the mapping of fields in Morphia?